# Alarm doesn't work if i press back button,Why?

Tags: android

Hi guys i am setting an alarm using the code below
the broadcast is setup inside the activity and hence is not registered in the manifest....

**The issue** :when i choose the time and set the alarm it works if i don't press back button and i don't destroy that activity but when i press back button,the alarm doesn't work

Code for setting the alarm

```
Log.i(String.valueOf(millisecond),convertedDate.toString());
            Log.i(date,convertedDate.toString());
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(ACTION_NAME);

             PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Reminder.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millisecond);
                        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);


                        Toast.makeText(Reminder.this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
```

broadcast receiver inside the same activity

```
BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          Intent x=  new Intent(context,MyAlarmService.class);
            startService (x);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous inner class to receive the broadcast. This class cannot be instantiated outside your app.

Implement a "normal" class to use as broadcast receiver, and register this receiver in the application manifest.

Comment: for some reasons it wasn't working earlier but it's working now,+1 for not asking me for useless codes ,and "what have you tried"